# Is there any English translation of Vivekachudamani bhashya by Shri Chandrashekara Mahaswamigal?

Tags: advaita, adi-shankaracharya, translation-request

Here is the link for the sanskrit work 
https://archive.org/details/VivekChudamaniBhashyaChandrasekharaBharati

Is there an English translation of the work?
If so please provide the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it's available to buy/purchase from Bharatiya Vidya Bhavan (Translated by P. Sankaranarayanan) at [Exotic India](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/vivekacudamani-of-sri-samkara-bhagavatpada-sanskrit-text-transliteration-and-detailed-commentary-IDK697/):

> [image]

Note: It seems the book is out of stock at Exotic India, Alternatively you can get it from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008RXWSYI).